# Random port number appended to URL when browsing Web App in Azure

Tags: url, ssl, https, azure-web-app-service, port-number

Whenever I browse to an **Azure Web App** I've published, a **random port number** (e.g. **44893**) is appended to the URL, resulting in a *Page cannot be displayed* error. The web app uses HTTPS.

What causes this?

Comment: What is your development language and how do you publish your web application to Azure Web App? Have you try to deploy your web application to a new web app to isolate this issue? Do all your pages could not be accessed or the specific page? Whether you have configured URL rewrite rules? Please provide more details about your issue, then we could help you to locate and solve this issue.

Comment: (1) Development Language: C#

(2) How was the web app published?: Web Deploy

(3) Have I deployed to a new web app to isolate this issue?: Yes, the issue still exists (so I'm guessing its something in the project).

(4) Do all your pages could not be accessed or the specific page?
The port number is generated on the "first page" I attempt to access.
E.g. If I attempt to access "https://example.com/Account/Login", it the URL that loads is "https://example.com:44351/Account/Login"

(5) Have I configured URL rewrite rules?: No

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assumed that this issue comes from your web application project. Since you have located the specific page which could encounter this issue, I suggest that you could debug your project and make sure it could work as expected on your development environment. For Azure Web App, you could follow this [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/09/22/remote-debug-your-azure-app-service-web-app/) for remoting debug. Also, you could leverage [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the network packages when you troubleshoot this issue. Additionally, if you could not find the cause, you could provide us with a sample project to reproduce this issue, then we could help you to locate and fix this issue.